# Knowledge Articles not being displayed on a VF page

Tags: knowledge

I have created a Force.com site and am trying to expose Knowledge articles to that site. I have created a VF page which will display a list of Knowledge articles. This page is the home page for force.com site.

If I open the page using `/apex/VF_Page_Name` I am able to see a list of knowledge articles. However, if I click on the site URL the page is loaded with list headings but no articles are listed. I have given access to all the fields in the Article.

Not sure which configuration I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Knowledge Article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticle.htm#topic-title) it has special security considerations...

> A user must have the “View Articles” permission enabled. Salesforce Knowledge users, unlike Customer Portal and partner portal users, must also be granted the Knowledge User feature license.

Maybe the guest user for your Force.com site need this permission?

Comment: So in the user profile, I am not seeing "View Articles" option. The user is assigned to the profile that was created when site was being setup

Comment: I wonder if the docs are out of date? I did find this btw, not sure if this something that might be useful for you? Have you seen it? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Su1DAAS

Comment: Also this, http://salesforceresources.com/tip_sheets/for_administrators/support_administration/salesforce_pkb_implementation_guide.pdf